# Open .drawio file in MxGraph Editor

Tags: xml, mxgraph, file-import

How to open a [.drawio](https://fileinfo.com/extension/drawio) XML file into [MxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/)?

In MxGraph we can import an XML file. But the structure of the `.drawio` file and MxGraph file are completely different, although both are XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Finally i found the way that how open draw io xml file in mxGraph. Before open we need to convert the draw io xml file into mxgraph xml file. Here using a decode function to convert draw io xml file into mxgraph xml file. Can use this decode method inside the xml call function.

Decode(data) {

```
    function bytesToString(arr) {
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            str += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
        }
        return str;
    }
    function parseXml(xml) {
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            return parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        } else {
            var result = createXmlDocument();
            result.async = "false";
            result.loadXML(xml);
            return result;
        }
    }
    function getTextContent(node) {
        return node != null
            ? node[node.textContent === undefined
                    ? "text"
                    : "textContent"]
            : "";
    }
    try {
        var node = parseXml(data).documentElement;
        if (node != null && node.nodeName === "mxfile") {
            var diagrams = node.getElementsByTagName("diagram");
            if (diagrams.length > 0) {
                data = getTextContent(diagrams[0]);
            }
            data = atob(data);
            data = bytesToString(Pako.inflateRaw(data));
            data = decodeURIComponent(data);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
    if (data.length > 0) {
        this.LoadGraph("", this.SelectGraphCell, data);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call the `decode` function and what is the expected input type/format of its parameter `data` ? BTW: code-block is out-of-formatting :)